# Increasing concurrent connections on ubuntu for iperf3 server

Tags: sockets, iperf

I'm trying to run a `iperf3` client (ubuntu server 17.04 VM) to server(ubuntu server 17.04 VM) test for maximum parallel streams possible with the -P option. Currently have reached a max of ~1022 streams before it will terminate with buffer overflow error. Have made the following changes to stretch the limits -
- Increased the `/etc/security/limits.conf` soft and hard limits for nofile to 16384
- Increases the ulimit to 16384

Are there any other changes that I can make to exceed the ~1022 limit that I am reaching?

Test:

iperf3 client:

```
iperf3 -c 10.37.129.4 -P 4096
```

iperf3 server:

```
iperf3 -s
```

Error:

```
root@ubuntu-server# iperf3 -s
-----------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on 5201
-----------------------------------------------------------
Accepted connection from 10.37.129.5, port 26967
[  5] local 10.37.129.4 port 5201 connected to 10.37.129.5 port 50920
[  6] local 10.37.129.4 port 5201 connected to 10.37.129.5 port 26980
*****output omitted***********
[1016] local 10.37.129.4 port 5201 connected to 10.37.129.5 port 24249
[1018] local 10.37.129.4 port 5201 connected to 10.37.129.5 port 42339
[1020] local 10.37.129.4 port 5201 connected to 10.37.129.5 port 10062
***** buffer overflow detected ***: iperf3 terminated**
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7908b)[0x7fa0cf99208b]
```

Answer (score 0):

That’s a security hole in iperf3.  I strongly suggest that you report it.